# Infinite summation of recursive integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, summation, problem-solving

> Let $I_n=\int_{0}^{1}e^{-y}y^n\ dy$, where $n$ is non-negative integer. Find  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{I_n}{n!}.$

---

I first solved $I_n$ and obtained $$I_n=-\frac{1}{e}+nI_{n-1} \\ 
 \hspace{35mm} =-\frac{1}{e}+n(-\frac{1}{e}+(n-1)I_{n-2}) \\ \hspace{72.7mm}=-\frac{1}{e}-n\frac{1}{e}-n(n-1)\frac{1}{e}-n(n-1)\frac{1}{e}+...+n!(I_1)$$

Since $$I_1=1-\frac{2}{e}\\ \therefore \frac{I_n}{n!}=-\frac{1}{e}(\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\frac{1}{(n-2)!}...+\frac{1}{2})+(1-\frac{2}{e})$$

I don't know what to do after this, because taking $e=2+1/2!+1/3!+1/4!+...+1/n!$ gives the value of $\frac{I_n}{n!}$ to be $0$.

How do I solve this?

Comment: $dx$ should be $dy$ and why are you not integrating from $0$ to $1$?

Comment: @Gary Typo, my bad.

Answer (score 5):

How about
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{I_n }}{{n!}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n!}}\int_0^1 {e^{ - y} y^n dy} }  = \int_0^1 {e^{ - y} \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{y^n }}{{n!}}} dy}  = \int_0^1 {e^{ - y} (e^y  - 1)dy}  = e^{ - 1} \,?
$$

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to bring the summation inside the integral!

Comment: You can use the monotone convergence theorem to justify it.